# Find the dept where more than avg. no of emps are working SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

List the name of the dept where more than avg. no of emps are working

**Table** emp_demo

```
emp_id   dname
1        d1
2        d2
3        d3
4        d2
5        d1
6        d2
```

There are 2 employees in D1, 3 employees in D2 and 1 employee in D3.

**Average number of employees will be (2+3+1/3) = 2 employees**
So the department with more than avg number of employees here will be D2 (with 3 employees).

**Query code made by me:**

```
select *
from emp_demo
group by dname
having count(emp_id) > AVG(count(emp_id))
```

**Error**

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by SQL Server not allowing an aggregate function to contain another aggregate function.

One way you can try to use CTE with subquery `JOIN`.

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT dname,COUNT(emp_id) cnt
    FROM emp_demo
    GROUP BY dname
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM cte t1 
JOIN (SELECT avg(cnt) avgCnt FROM cte) t2
ON t1.cnt > t2.avgCnt
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=318008a58685bd46f6e8c81df1cc83f7)

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the average number of `emp_id` using a variable.  This has a subquery that calculates the count per `dname` then the main query runs an average over that.

The second part of the query is an information-only line telling you what the average it has worked out is.  Not needed if you don't want it.

The third part runs the count again, but filtering out `dname` entries that are not greater than the `@avg_emps` variable calculated at the start:

```
declare @avg_emps int = (
    select 
    avg(emp_count) as avg_emp_count
    from (
        select
        dname
        ,count(emp_id) as emp_count
        from dbo.foo
        group by dname
    ) as count_emps
    )

select 'Average employees per department is: ' + cast(@avg_emps as varchar(10));

select
dname
from dbo.foo
group by dname
having count(emp_id) > @avg_emps;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE which returns the average numbers of employees in each department:

```
with cte as (
  select dname, count(*) counter
  from emp_demo
)
select dname
from cte
where counter > (select avg(counter) from cte)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work without use of any variables:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp_demo
GROUP by dname
HAVING count(emp_id) > (
    SELECT AVG(r1.c1)
    from (
        SELECT count(emp_id)) as c1
        FROM emp_demo
        GROUP by dname
    ) as r1
)
```

Comment: `AVG(count(emp_id)` is not a valid sql expression.

Comment: Echoing @forpas, the question even has this syntax in it described as not working along with the error!